# Laravel Eloquent Many-To-Many distinct

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, many-to-many, distinct

I have a `Player` Model which has many `Teams` and each `Teams` has many `Player` (Many-To-Many).

**Player FooBar** is a member of **Team A** and **Team B**.
I would like to retrieve all the (distinct) players from Team A and B directly from my `Player` Model. Of course, each teams have many players, some similar, some different.

My player model example

```
class Player extends Model 
{
     teams(){

         return $this->hasMany('Teams');

     }

      teammates(){

           //Returns all the players from the teams where the player belongs

      }
}
```

**What I would like to be able to do**

```
$player = Player::find($id);

//Gets all the players from every team the player is playing with
$teammates = $user->teammates();
```

Comment: Try adding `return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Teams', 'App\Player')->distinct()` This should retrieve all players for all teams that the user belongs to. Method chaining `distinct` onto the Eloquent query builder may not work as intended, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The "has-many-through" relationship provides a convenient short-cut for accessing distant relations via an intermediate relation. For example, a Country model might have many Post models through an intermediate User model. In this example, you could easily gather all blog posts for a given country

I believe you should try using a hasManyThrough relationship, see [Laravel Documentation on Has Many Through Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through).

```
$this->hasManyThrough('Teams', 'Player');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a pivot table linking users and teams. You can create a model such as TeamUser:

```
class TeamUser extends Model {

protected $table = 'team_user';

  public function users()
  {
     return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
  }

   public function teams()
  {
     return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Team');
  }

}
```

Then you can try this:

```
$user = User::find($id);
$teams = $user->teams()->lists('id');
$players = UserTeam::with('users')->whereIn('team_id', $teams)->get();
```

This query gives you the list of players.